# Is there any way to save pytorch models with their classes

Tags: pytorch

When i try to load my saved model, i need to import its class. For example:

```py
from module import Net
torch.load('saved_model.pth')
```

Is there any way to avoid this importing?. For example saving the model with class or something else?

Comment: Where are you using `Net`?

Comment: I load the model in another module, not where the Net was described

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply load the model into a known nn.Module object such as `net` you can use `torch.load_state_dict('saved_model.pth')`. If you want the entire model saved so someone else can use it you'll have to use to pickle:

```py
import pickle
 
net = Net()
with open('saved_model.pth', 'w') as filehandler: 
    pickle.dump(net, filehandler)
```

to load:

```py
with open('saved_model.pth', 'w') as filehandler:
    net = pickle.load(filehandler)
```

However it is highly recommended not to use pickle as it may save stuff custom to your machine / environment and cause it to not work on someone else's machine. If you really must use pickle it may be worth looking if you can decouple the class from the neural network, save the class in a pickle file and the parameters in a torch file.

Hope this helps and isn't just stuff you know.